# Environmental Variables are not reflected until restarting the machine

Tags: scripts, environment-variables, bashrc, restart, .profile

I know there are similar questions for mine, but still they weren't helpful with my issue.

Scenario:
I set a variable in either
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
/etc/environment

Whether the variable is assigned as
FUN=/home/user/fun
or
export FUN=/home/user/fun
or
export set FUN=/home/user/fun
or
export setenv FUN=/home/user/fun

After saving changes and opening a new shell

```
echo $FUN

# but if I do
source ~/.profile
echo $FUN
/home/user/fun
```

This is not the case when I restart the machine btw running Ubuntu 16.04.
I don't see to source.

Further, I have scripts that run and try to use that variable. Even when I source the ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc or /etc/environment , the scripts fail to find the variable and only after restarting the machine, it works.

I'm happy to try any suggestions, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of rebooting, just try logging out and log back in. Things in `/etc/environment` will be processed by the login program (I think). Things in `~/.profile` are processed by a *login shell*. Things in `~/.bashrc` are processed by an *interactive* shell. See [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) in the bash manual.

Comment: @glennjackman: Things in `~/.profile` are also sourced at login by the display manager (e.g. LightDM or GDM). The page [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) is good reading on this topic.

Comment: Yes, logging out without restart the machine did the trick. I'm reading the links now to understand how to apply the variable changes without logging out and logging back in. Also I have no preference who these variables are stored, bashrc, profile, environment. It seems like it is same effect. Thanks for the reply back.